# Why does re-opening an app on iOS11+ un-pause SpriteKit Nodes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpriteNode in a scene that has animations built into it from the SpriteKit scene editor. None of the animations are done via code. The skspritenode is imported into the scene from a .sks file.

I've tested on an iPad Pro running iOS 10.3.2 and it works fine, whereas on an iPhone XS Max running iOS 12, the animations only play once I close the app (or even just exit out to multitasking) and return back in. The animations don't start to play on the app first launch.

I've read about: "as of iOS11 Apple has made the default state for scenes and SKSpriteNodes to be paused." So to fix I told the imported node:

nodeName.isPaused = false. And this fixed the problem.

Why does exiting the app and re-opening it tell something to un-pause?

Comment: Because that is the way apple wants it, and I am not joking.  They literally told me that is the intended behavior when I argues about how they handle IsPaused

Comment: Mhm, shouldn't the developer of the game determine when something is un-paused when an app opens? And why automatically set something as paused when it's imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to `IsPaused`, your scene will set this property to true when leaving an app, and set it to false when returning from the app. This will cause all of your nodes to set the IsPaused variable to false and true as well.

I recommend overriding the IsPaused property, and link the getter and setter to a private variable in your own class.

You can also use an || with the built in isPaused in case you want to do things with it.

```
class GameScene : SKScene
{
    private var _realPaused  = false
    public override var isPaused : Boolean
    {
        get
        {
            return super.isPaused || _realPaused
        }
        set
        {
            super.isPaused = newValue // this will mess with your children nodes if they are not the same value as parent,  preserve all children prior to setting this if needed
        }
    }
}
```